# mongoose get data via unknown path

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to write code which is supposed to get data from a database with an unknown path. I have probably tried to do it in an overcomplicated way, and even the way I'm doing it isn't correct. If you have any idea how to simplify my problem, feel free to explain your own solution ansted of trying to correct my bad code.

[image]

The problem is that there can be more than just 1 Objects in ``fieldarr`. And I need to somehow get the` value`by the`mode`. (Meaning that the only thing I know to get the value is the mode.)
What I've tried:

```js
import queue from "../schemas/queue";

const allArr = await queue.where('_id').equals('628e1d05369f0c34c39e86d2').select('fieldarr') as any
const objectId = allArr[0]
let prevValue = await queue.find({ _id: '628e1d05369f0c34c39e86d2'}).select('fieldarr.' + objectId + '.content.value')
prevValue = prevValue.slice(0, -2)
prevValue = parseInt(prevValue) + 1
await queue.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: '628e1d05369f0c34c39e86d2' }, {
    fieldarr: {
        content: {
            value: prevValue + '/' + 2
        }
    }
}).exec()
```

The problem with that code tho, is that it doesn't get the `objectId` by the `mode` and it also throws the following error:

```
          callback(new MongoServerError(document));
                   ^
MongoServerError: Path collision at }.content.value remaining portion content.value
```

Here's the schema:

```js
import mongoose from 'mongoose'
const field = {
    content: { type: Object },
    mode: { type: String }
}

const queue = new mongoose.Schema({
    activefields: { type: Number },
    fieldarr: [ field ]
})

export default mongoose.model('quueue', queue, 'queue')
```

Comment: shoudln't --  mongoose.Types.ObjectId(<someId>) -- be used?

Answer (score 0):

You're nearly reach it
you don't need to call .exec() after

```
await queue.findOneAndUpdate(
{ _id: '628e1d05369f0c34c39e86d2'},
{"fieldarr.content.value": prevValue + '/' + 2}
)//dont need .exec()
```